# PhD admission product $\lim_{n\to 0}\left(\frac21\left(\frac32\right)^2\left(\frac43\right)^3\cdots\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$

Tags: limits, products

Hello there I saw this problem (#3) here:
http://www.sau.int/admission/2018/samplepapers/PAM.pdf

> $$L=\lim_{n\to 0} \left( \frac{2}{1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^3...\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n\right)^\frac{1}{n}$$
>   The choices for the answer are $e$, $\pi$, $\frac{1}{e}$, $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

If we take the logartihm on both sides we get: $$\ln L=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\ln\frac{k+1}{k}$$ thus by telescoping $$\ln L= \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)$$ and now using wolfram I get the answer to be $L=e^\gamma$, which is not one of the choices.

Where did I go wrong? And could you share the correct solution?

Comment: Are you sure its the limit as n goes to zero?

Comment: well, I just copied the original problem.

Comment: I would expect $L=e$ from Stirling's approximation

Comment: @DavidDiaz: I was going to ask the same thing ... The linked PDF *does* have $n\to 0$. That must be a typo, however. A limit as "number of factors approaches zero" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Using Cesaro-Stolz you get the answer immediately as $e$.

Comment: In the document, it looks more to me like it says $h\rightarrow{0}$, so I suspect it's a typo from copying from the previous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{n+1}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \approx \dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}^{1/n}\dfrac n e} \to e$$

Comment: @Dahaka my limit of $e$  is as $n \to \infty$.  You would need a different approximation as $n \to 0$ and that indeed may have a limit of $e^\gamma$, but $n\to 0$ makes no sense in terms of the original product which has $n$ as an increasing integer

Comment: That's what I got from computer experimentatino.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

after simplification,

$$\ln (L)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\Bigl (\ln(n+1)-\frac {1}{n}\ln (n!)\Bigr)= $$

Answer (score 0):

Of the sequence $a_n=(1+\frac1n)^n$ which we know converges to $e$ the task asks you to consider the **geometric mean** sequence
$$
b_n=\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}.
$$
The logarithm of that has the form
$$
\ln b_n=\frac{\ln a_1+\ln a_2+\dots+\ln a_n}n
$$
which by the theorem about the **Cesaro mean** or by the more general **theorem of Cesaro-Stolz** converges to the same limit as the quotient sequence $\frac{\ln a_n}1$, if that exists. As we know that this limit exists and is $1$, the sequence $\ln b_n$ has the same limit and thus $b_n$ converges to $e$.